# Xbox controller only for Games? Can media (e.g. photo) not be browsed with it on macOS?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, games

Quote from [Apple starts selling Microsoft’s Xbox controller after adding support in iOS, macOS, and tvOS](https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/9/20906569/apple-microsoft-xbox-wireless-controller-ios-macos-tvos-support-price)

> Apple has begun selling Microsoft’s Xbox Wireless Controller after
> adding support for the gamepad in the latest major software updates
> for iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, and the Mac. The Xbox controller is priced
> at $59.95 and is available from Apple’s website.

I paired the [Xbox Wireless Controller Series S with macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211232) and could not operate the normal Desktop with the controller. I assume the controller only works in games? I would like to use a media player or image browser with the controller. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application doesn't have to be a game to support controllers, however applications (game or not) do have to add support for controllers.

The system handles connecting to the controllers, but the application still has to respond to the new keypresses/signals it receives from the operating system.

Photos does not respond to these signals and does not support controllers.